# Displaying glyphicon next to controls (Razor with Bootstrap)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display a glyphicon directly to the right of my input controls. The following code includes a large space between the control and glyphicon. None of the solutions I've tried properly fix the issue without stacking all controls vertically, or adding the glyphicon next to the validation message (instead of the control. How can I fix this?

```html
            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-2">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubmitterLocation)</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubmitterLocation, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SubmitterLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="#" title="Dismissible popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Click anywhere in the document to close this popover" data-placement="right">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" height="42" width="42" style="text-align:center;" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group col-md-4">@Html.LabelFor(sm => sm.SubmitterLocation)
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubmitterLocation, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <a href="#" title="Dismissible popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Click anywhere in the document to close this popover" data-placement="right">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SubmitterLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

What I did here is that I added class **input-group** on div you want to have an icon. Re-arrange your html elements and put the icon next to textbox, and add a class **input-group-addon** on span class.

It shall now look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm having the same problem. The glyphicon is showing way to the right of the control.

Comment: Glad to help! Kindly mark it as an answer as reference to others.